# Is there any Javascript code-coverage tool for script running on server side (no browser)

Tags: javascript, testing, code-coverage

Strategy-decision logic is held in javascript file. Service, which is written in Cpp, send request to this file and get decision. I would like to find code-coverage tool which allows me to see which javascript statements were covered during my testing. Tools that I found so far are testing client part and require index.html and running via browser.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard a lot of good things about [JsChiliCat](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jschilicat/index.php?title=Main_Page) for headless JS testing, but I've never used it myself. In general, you may want to search for "headless javascript code coverage".